# An Exercise from Liebeck's 'A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics'

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

The exercise reads: 'Find an integer $n$ and a rational $t$ such that $n^t=2^{1/2}3^{1/3}$.
Here is my attempt of solution:
$$n^t=2^{1/2}3^{1/3}\Rightarrow n^{2t}=2\times 3^{2/3}\Rightarrow n^{6t}=2^33^2=72.$$
Therefore, a suitable choise is $t=1/6$ and $n=72$.

Is my solution a proper one? Is there any quicker solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: What you have done is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, if you take into account the basic principles of exponential solving, namely:
\begin{align}
n^{6t} = 72 &\implies n^{6t} = 72^{1}\\
&\implies \begin{cases} n = 72\\ 6t =1  \end{cases}\\
&\implies \begin{cases} n =72\\ t = \dfrac{1}{6} \end{cases}.
\end{align}

I am just adding this in for completeness sake, since I know too many teachers that would not have given you full credit for this if you did not go this far.